# Android unable to get current location using GPS when device is not moving

Tags: android, android-gps

I want to get current latitude and longitude of device even when it is not in movement.

Tried both `requestLocationUpdates()` and `requestSingleUpdate()` but my location is still null. `LocationManager.onLocationChanged()` seems to be called only when location gets changed. I want to post this location details but fails with `NullPointerException` every time.

Here are my code samples:

**Activity:**

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, myLocationListener);

        if (location == null) {
            try {
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, myLocationListener, Looper.myLooper());                        
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
            }
        }

       //MyLocationListener    
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           activity.setLocation(location);
       }
   }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: try with another phone

Comment: Are you using the device indoors? The GPS takes a long time to get a location fix indoors.

Comment: yes I am using indoors

Comment: @basilisk Is there any way to consistently get location. Fine if it takes some time rather than me ensuring it through some 'TimerTask' or kind of

Answer (score 1):

If the user has not used GPS for a while, there will be no last known location, hence the GPS provider will not update at all unless you move outside. Its better to use the new FusedLocationApi to get updates as it selects the best source for you and gives you the best possible location.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @basilisk...Will try FusedLocationAPI

Answer (score 0):

Trying putting your code in AsyncTask.